# Group name as claim in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, claims

I have an enterprise app used to send claims to an on-prem ADFS.
I need to send the group **names** my Guest users belong to. I know that OOTB you can only send the Gpoup ID. 
As suggested in other posts I can use the Graph API to get the group name, but how can I then send this as claim?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's only possible to get the object ids as of right now. This may be implemented in the future, however, in order to get the group names you will need to have some sort of service that makes calls to the Microsoft graph utilizing the ID.

Please raise the [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) or vote for similar [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38483242-option-to-show-group-name-in-groups-claims)